# About Struts Grammar

Tags: struts2

Below is a line from a Struts config file. What do `'comp/*/*/*'` and `{1}` mean?

`<action name="comp/*/*/*" class="com.fxoa.comp.{1}.action.extjs.{2}Action" method="{3}">`

Comment: are you sure this is the whole code?

Comment: no,and now i partly know what it is supposed to do.{1} represent first *,{2} represents sencond * and so no. but what does ${nextPath} mean?

Comment: @user1093382 either post complete code else its hard for anyone to answer you question `${nextPath}` where is this in your code??just to let you know this is a way to extract dynamic values from the stack in your configuration file

Comment: sorry,i didnot post whole context because  i think these wildcards should be well known beyond who good at using struts.

Comment: @user1093382 yes they are but its always best to post whole content it will always help other to know whole context.

Comment: If there's a `${nextPath}` in the config file then it's an OGNL expression used to get an action property at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called as `Wildcards` mappings when your application size grows `Wildcards` can be used to combine similar mappings into one more generic mapping.
What you are showing in your example is also known as wildcard mapping.It can be done at 2 levels

1. Action level
2. Method levels

Read official documentation for details

[Wildcard-Mappings](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/wildcard-mappings.html)

[WildcardMethod](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/action-configuration.html#ActionConfiguration-WildcardMethod)

Comment: @user1093382 if this is what you are looking for don't forget to mark the question as accepted :)